# ImageView in Tab graphics

Tags: javafx

I have a simple TabUtil-Class that creates me a `Tab` with an overgiven `ImageView` as a title.

```
public static Tab createIconTab(ImageView icon) {
    Tab tab = new Tab();
    tab.setGraphic(icon);
    System.out.println("create tab: +");
    icon.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("CLICKED");
        }
    });
    return tab;
}
```

With three other tabs it produces me the following UI. If I click on the tab with the "+"-icon nothing happens. CLICKED is not beeing printed out... I also tried to set the EventHandler on the graphic component. Again nothing happens...But why?

[image: Tabs Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a similar problem and resolved it by putting the ImageView into a Label first, like so:

```
public static Tab createIconTab(ImageView icon) 
{
    Label  iconLabel = new Label();
    iconLabel.setGraphic( icon );
    iconLabel.setContentDisplay( ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY  );
    iconLabel.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("CLICKED");
        }
    });

    Tab tab = new Tab();
    tab.setGraphic( iconLabel );
    return tab;
}
```